# Как устранить многозначность фразы с "и" и "или"?

Tags: союзы

Пример фразы:

*по ключевому слову «икра» или «протез» и упоминанию любого числительного и любого земноводного.*

Какие две части соединяет "или" и какие "и"?

Comment: Сейчас мне сложно быстро вникнуть в ваш комментарий и grizzly, но скажите, почему "протез" должен быть без кавычек? В чём смысл?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Это какой-то глюк. Я ничего не менял нарочно, только зашёл в правку и вышел. В любом случае, к сути вопроса это отношения не имело.

Comment: Так было в оригинале. Не знаю, закладывал ли автор в это смысл или нет.

Если исход рассматриваемого здесь вопроса это меняет, то хотел бы знать, как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря комментариям к другому ответу стало понятнее, в чём суть вопроса.

Русский язык — это естественный язык, а не формальный. Поэтому неудачные формулировки на нём могут приводить к подобной неоднозначности понимания. Иногда неоднозначность разрешается благодаря контексту, но в общем случае необходимо строить предложения так, чтобы подобных разночтений не возникало. Например, можно использовать другие союзы, вводные сочетания (*кроме того*, *а также* и т.п.) или дать поясняющие комментарии.

> Какие две части соединяет "или" и какие "и"?

Очевидно, вопрос о том, что подразумевал автор, нужно переадресовать автору, а не аудитории.

Comment: Спасибо.

Автор имел ввиду `(по ключевому слову «икра») или (протез и упоминанию любого числительного и любого земноводного)`.

Стало интересно, что нам позволяет язык и как избежать подобных неоднозначностей. Очень неприятная ситуация, согласитесь.


Верно ли я понимаю, фраза, с точки зрения русского языка, полностью корректна?

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, всё понятно. *Или* соединяет *икру* и *протез.* Первое *и* соединяет всё, что до него и после. А второе *и* соединяет *любое числительное* и *любое земноводное.*

Comment: Не уверен, что всё так однозначно. Формально, данному условию удовлетворяет только одновременное упоминание одного из ключевых слов, числительного и земноводного. Но я предполагаю, что подразумевается одновременное упоминание ключевого слова и [числительного или земноводного]. А может даже так: ключевое слово, или числительное, или земноводное. А какое понимание предполагаете Вы?

Comment: Первое `и` соединяет всё, что до него включая `"икру"`?

Для упрощения воспользуюсь скобками.

`(по ключевому слову «икра» или протез) и (упоминанию любого числительного и любого земноводного)`

или же

`(по ключевому слову «икра») или (протез и упоминанию любого числительного и любого земноводного)`

Пожалуй последнее `и` не нуждается в пояснении.



Я бы задал дополнительный вопрос: существует ли понятие ассоциативности союзов?

Comment: Я понял так, как у вас в первом варианте.